# Jquery UI's calling static method of a widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Is there a way to call method statically from the widget? I have two methods of my own:

```
on: function() { .. },
off: function() { .. }
```

which basically turn on and off all of the instances of my widget. How can I call them statically?  Using `$.ui.widgetName.on()` returns type error (has no method).

Comment: what is returned from those methods?

Comment: @ArunPJohny Just a `true` for now. `$.ui.widgetName.on()` returns type error (has no method).

Comment: If i declare the method private (`_on`), i can access it through prototype no problem, but that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a not so great but working solution. Simply pulled methods from the prototype:

```
$.ui.hint.turnOn = function(par) { return $.ui.hint.prototype.turnOn(par)};
$.ui.hint.turnOff = function(par) { return $.ui.hint.prototype.turnOff(par)};
```

So now I can just access them anywhere statically:

```
$.ui.hint.turnOn();
$.ui.hint.turnOff();
```